# Nginx behaving in a strange way

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am having a difficult time getting nginx to work on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.

The following is my configuration at the moment, nothing else is enabled. The `include/example.ssl.conf` contains some common settings for configuring SSL.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name test.example.com;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.nginx-debian.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name code.example.com;

  include include/example.ssl.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
  }
}
```

For some reason when I hit `http://test.example.com` I get no response, the browser times out after a while. If I hit `https://code.example.com` it works and I get redirected to the login page of my `code-server`. Strangely, any `https`-subdomain gets proxied to my `code-server` on port 8443, and I don't understand why this is happening. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like port 80 of your server is unreachable. Since the code-server listens at port 443 (https), it will always reply to *any* of your requests coming through https (provided that your DNS is redirecting all domains to your server, which means your domain has some wildcard record like `*.example.com` configured), that explains your "strange" behavior.

You should check your firewall configuration to make sure you can access your server from port 80, which is the default HTTP port. That should make the server work from that port and redirect to your static content, which should also be there (place an index.html at `/var/www/html`).

For the rest, I can't see any other issues so far, so it must be either port 80 unreachable or missing content.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The reason why the http part didn't work was, just like you stated, because the firewall was not configured correctly. Also, just like you mention, I do have a wildcard record setup in my DNS, but I'd like a restriction such that only `code.example.com` proxies to my `code-server`, not all other subdomains. How would I go about that? I thought the `server_name` directive would take care of that. Maybe I am uninformed and need to read the docs

Comment: From [Nginx - Request processing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) : "If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port.". If nginx can't find any server to attend the request, it will take the first available server name listening at that port. You can avoid this behavior by following the guide, [How to prevent processing requests with undefined server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated!